# javascript variable value to php variable and loading tab content by default

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

```
var Result; 
$(document).ready(function(){  
location.href="index.php?Result=" +1;  
    $("a").click(function(){        
        Result=$(this).attr('id');   
        location.href="index.php?Result=" + Result;

    })
});

<div id="tabs">
    <ul> 
        <?php include "config.php"; 
        $query = "select * from tabs"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query); 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $name = $row['name']; $tabid = $row['tabid']; 
            echo '<li><a id="' . $tabid . '" href="#' . $name . '"> ' . $name . '</a></li>'; 
        } ?> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hie,
    I have seven tabs,which are fetched from database using mysql query,Onclick on each tab am passing the tab value from javascript to php variable and by using that tabvalue am running the required querys to load the data into tabs,My issue is am unable to load the first tab content by default,on click the first tab content is loading properly,i want that first tab content to load by default here am using jquery ui tabs,when i followed the above code by calling first tab before onclick it is loading multiple times....and even focus is moving to first tab by default...suggest any solution......thanks....

Comment: If you are using **jquery ui tabs** then where is its code? The above code will redirect to the given urls.

Comment: Here is the tabs code....<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <?php
            include "config.php";
            $query = "select * from tabs";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               
                $name = $row['name'];
                $tabid = $row['tabid'];
                echo '<li><a id="' . $tabid . '" value=' . $name . ' href="#' . $name . '"> ' . $name . '</a></li>';
            }
            ?>
        </ul></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, you are redirecting to index.php from the same file. So during the first execution of document ready function, it redirects you to the same file with a different query string parameter. But since the document ready function will execute again now, it keeps on reloading.

The simplest approach will be to handle this in PHP, when the "Result" parameter is not set, make it as 1.

In a javascript way, you can grab the query string value and check if "Result" parameter is set. If its not set then redirect the page to index.php?Result=1.

A javascript way of getting query string parameter is below.

```
function param(name)
{
var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
var query = url.split('?')[0];
var data = query.split('&');
    for(var i in data)
    {
      if(data[i].split('=')[0] == name)
      {
         return data[i].split('=')[1];
      }
    }
}
```

You can call it by using

```
var page_num = param('Result');
if(page_num == null)
{
   location.href = 'index.php?Result=1';
}
```

Comment: So, you need the content of first tab displayed, but no tab should be focussed?

Comment: yes....no tab should be focused (or) the relevant tab should be focused with the content....but here tabs and content loading is working fine....but tab focus is moving to first tab.....i hope you got what i want to say

Comment: I guess you mean, when the person clicks 5th tab, the content of 5th tab loads but the focus of tab name goes to first tab? 
Or is the focus of tab name and content both moves to first tab?

Comment: yes .... content of 5th tab loads but the focus of tab name goes to first tab ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var Result = 1; 
 $(document).ready(function(){  
   location.href="index.php?Result=" + Result;  
   $("a").click(function(){        
      Result=$(this).attr('id');   
      location.href="index.php?Result=" + Result;

  })
})
```

Comment: yes it will reload.. since your are calling location.href... to load dynamically you need to use ajax to get the content without reloading

Answer (score 0):

```
var Result; 
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("a").click(function(){        
        Result=$(this).attr('id');   
        location.href="index.php?Result=" + Result;

    })
}
```

And Body tag

```
<body onload="location.href='index.php?Result=1'">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger automatically first tab click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.parent > a').trigger('click');
</script>
```